# Restore differential backup SQL Server 2014

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, database-restore

I have full, differential and transactional backups of the database. I was trying to restore one by one; but only the full backup is getting restored, but after that when I am trying to restore the differential backup facing issue with SQL Server Management Studio. So I tried with some SQL commands, this is the link what I tried with to restore, but no luck

[Restore differential backup](http://sqlmag.com/database-backup-and-recovery/step-step-approach-differential-backup-and-recovery)

Can anyone tell me the steps tor restore these backups? Thank you

Comment: What are the issues you're facing?

Comment: when i started with commands it restored the database but it was showing the (restoring..)  like this in front of the database name. but nothing is happened after that.

Comment: Don't add details in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and explain the problem you're having there, where people can see it. Details belong in the question itself.

Comment: You probably didn't complete the restore sequence and the last command you ran was a RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY command. If you look at the article the last command you run is a RESTORE WITH RECOVERY.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to be acquainted with the **restore sequence** of how a full database backup is restored.

First, restore **full database backup**, **differential database backup** and **all transaction log backups** `WITH NORECOVERY` option. After that, bring back database online using `WITH RECOVERY` option.

Following is a sample Restore Sequence

```
RESTORE DATABASE FROM full_database_backup WITH NORECOVERY;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE FROM differential_backup WITH NORECOVERY;
GO
RESTORE LOG FROM log_backup WITH NORECOVERY;
GO
-- Repeat this until you restore last log backup
RESTORE DATABASE WITH RECOVERY;
GO
```

**Note:**

While performing a `RESTORE` operation using more than one file, always use the `NORECOVERY` flag. This will keep the database offline to prevent any changes which could create some integrity issues. Once all the backup files have been restored, run the `RESTORE` command with the `RECOVERY` option **to get the database online and operational**.

Source: [URL](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/15/sql-server-restore-sequence-and-understanding-norecovery-and-recovery/)